# autocomplete as expected multiple values are not listing out in the result area

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently working on angularjs + map + autocomplete with my current code i am getting map and autocomplete but the problem begins when i started search the value in autocomplete let say for example i am searching letter  **The** I am getting only one result in my list not all **the** value which is available. And currently i am trying to hide using ng-hide i am display column only when i fetch the data i need to see display column. What I am doing wrong here.

HTML code

```
 <autocomplete  options="datas" 
                    place-holder="Search options..."
                    on-select="onSelect" 
                    display-property="title"
                    input-class="form-control"
                    clear-input="false"></autocomplete>
```

**display data**

```
<ul class="ng-hide">
        <li class="li_list">
            {{selectedData.title}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

here is my angular code

```
    $scope.selectedData = null;
$scope.datas = [
    {title: 'The dog', age: 2},
    {title: 'The cat', age: 4},
    {title: 'The bird', age: 7}
];
$scope.onSelect = function(selection) {
    console.log(selection);
    $scope.selectedData = selection;

};
```

Comment: can you create a working demo of your problem?